# Html, jQuery, how to submit a form which is deleted?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a popup and a form in it. After clicking "save" the popup disappears, so `form.submit()` wont work after this. I tried to clone it: `var form = $(this).clone();` then form.submit() with no effect.

Comment: First submit the form and then only hide it.

Comment: not possible due to 3rd party flow :(

Comment: It sounds like you're removing the form from the DOM, just use .hide() instead. (edit, didnt see the comments above)

Comment: also send your code also

Comment: right .. first submit get all values in global ..than later carry out your save functionality

Comment: Before clicking "save"  serialize the form and save it in a variable.

Comment: Then show us the function of save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please try this**

```
var form = $("form").serialize();
//close the window
//submit the form
```

OR Try ajax

```
$j.ajax({
    url: path,
    type: "POST",
    data: $("form").serialize(),
    success:function(data){

    },
    error:function(){ 
        alert('Oops...mistake on server');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: TypeError: form.submit is not a function

Comment: Try to submit it via ajax

Comment: clone will get the full code , but how will you submit ?? @JohnSmith